# Jenkins Buildmaster Dependency-Track does not react to Yarn Resolutions

Tags: javascript, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, yarnpkg, yarn-v2

We are using [Jenkins Dependency-Track](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/dependency-track/) and it's reporting that we have vulnerable dependencies. Many of these are coming from deep sub-dependencies of our packages so we do not have the option of upgrading the packages directly. It seems like the correct solution here is to use [Yarn resolutions](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) in order to globally pin updated versions of the vulnerable dependencies. Doing this correctly sets the version numbers in our yarn.lock, however the vulnerability report remains unchanged.
[image]

Does anyone know what the problem could be? We are using Yarn v2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was happening because our main project has a sub-project with its own `package.json` that is used for QA purposes. Its dependencies were not being shown when doing `yarn why <dep>` which gave the false impression that everything was updated.